# Does the squared root $\sqrt{|\cdot|}$ belong to $BV((-1,1))$?

Tags: measure-theory, bounded-variation, geometric-measure-theory

Does the squared root belong $\sqrt{|\cdot|}$ to $BV((-1,1))$? In an affirmative case, what is its derivative in the distributional sense, i.e., what is the Radon measure $\mu$ such that $\mu=Du$ ?

Comment: what is $u$ here?

Comment: In this case, $Du$ means the distributional derivative of the function $u$ defined by $t\mapsto \sqrt{|t|}$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both of your questions are answered by the following identity: 
$$\sqrt{|x|}= 1+\frac12\int_{-1}^x |t|^{-1/2} \operatorname{sign} t \,dt$$